# Unable to retrieve value from a Map with object of identical values

Tags: dictionary, ecmascript-6

I want to construct a lookup table with an object as key. However I find that I cannot construct a key with the same values to retrieve the value in the table.

```js
const makeKey = (a, b) => (
  {a, 
   b,}
);

const lookup = new Map();

lookup.set(makeKey(1, 2), 'YES');
lookup.set(makeKey(3, 7), 'NO');
console.log(lookup.keys());

const k = makeKey(1, 2)

console.log(k);
console.log(lookup.get(k));  // want to get YES, get undefined instead
```

It seems like the Map uses object identity to find a hit.

How can I use an object's value as key?

Comment: You could make a top-level Map with `a` as the key, where each value is a Map and each of those maps has `b` values as keys, and the `YES` and `NO` values as the values. As you said, Maps are keyed on object identity, so it's up to you do make that work with your goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up change the way the key is generated:

```
const makeKey = (a, b) => {
  const k = {a, b};
  return `${Object.values(k)}`
};
```

The key is now a string

Comment: That's the same as `[a, b].join(",")` FYI. I'd probably go that route since it's easier to read.